# Pergunta mais bem elaborada / específica

Tags: debate

Ultimamente estava procurando informação sobre uma determinada função dai procurei e encontrei no stack EN.

Contudo eu pesquisei no PT-BR e encontrei uma resposta que mesmo assim não solucionava o meu problema, a pergunta estava de correta para a pessoa mas não respondia minha questão EX:

*Como enviar email usando Laravel Mail::sender()*

*Como enviar email usando Laravel Mail::sender() passando informações por parâmetro.*

Pode ser uma coisa bem meio boba mas faria toda a diferença, pelo menos no meu caso sim, esse tipo de pergunta eu devo sinalizar ou devo fazer um nova pergunta? Lembrando para quem fez a pergunta teve uma solução mas para minha pessoa não!
Lembrando que mudando um pouco a pergunta pode mudar o contexto.

Posso estar errado contudo.Criar perguntas mais específicas podem gera duplicata ou é bom pra poder ter mais detalhes sobre um determinado problema, ou é apenas o café que eu bebi de mais(sem açúcar).

Comment: Se você encontrou a solução no site em inglês, porque não posta uma resposta baseada nela na pergunta que já existe em português, explicando como proceder quando for necessário passar parâmetros? Agora, se achar que a pergunta é diferente o suficiente, pode postar uma nova e responder você mesmo. O sistema permite postar o par pergunta/resposta ao mesmo tempo, inclusive.

Comment: Creio que não passei a ideia correta, a pergunta era em português mas não atende minha minha abrange minha pergunta que eu mandei no exemplo.
Tudo bem da próxima vez eu abro uma nova pergunta passando mais informação que possa ajudar mais ainda a comunidade.